# For $x+y=2p, p \in \mathbb{P}$, there are visible points $v=p-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, semiprimes

**Conjecture**

For $x+y=2p, p \in \mathbb{P}$, there are [visible points](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) $v=p-1$.

**Example**

Let $p=7$, then $v=6$.

[image: even_semiprimes]

Similarly for

$p=11 \rightarrow v=10$
$p=13 \rightarrow v=12$
$p=17 \rightarrow v=16$
...

**Question**

How to prove the conjecture for any $p$?

Comment: Hint: $(x,y)$ visible $\!\iff\! 1\! =\! (x,y)\! =\! (x,2p\!-\!x)\! =\! (x,2p)$. There are $\phi(2p)=p\!-\!1$ such naturals $\,x\le 2p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are only interested in points in the positive quadrant of the plane. Recall that a point $(a, b)$ is visible  from the origin if and only if $\mathrm{gcd}(a, b) = 1$.

Now, the points that lie on the line $y = -x + 2p$ in the positive quadrant are of the form $(i, 2p - i)$ for $i \in \{0, \ldots, 2p\}$.

If $i$ is even, then $\mathrm{gcd}(i, 2p - i) \geq 2$, hence these points are not visible from the origin.

If $i$ is odd, we show that the only point that is not visible from the origin is the point $(p, p)$. Assume that $\mathrm{gcd}(i, 2p - i) = d > 1$, then we have $i = da$, $2p - i = db$ for some integers $a, b$. Since $i$ is odd, $d$ must odd as well. Since $2p = d(a + b)$ you have that $d \mid 2p$, so we must have $d \mid p$. Hence $d = p$. Thus, the only point $(i, 2p - i)$ with $i$ odd that is not visible from the origin is the point $(p, 2p - i) = (p, p)$.

Thus, since there are $p - 1$ odd numbers in the interval $[0, 2p]$ that are not equal to $p$, we conclude there are $p - 1$ visible points.

Comment: @vengy  The answer essentially computes the well-known [Euler totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\,\phi(2p)= p-1,\,$ see my comment on the question.

Comment: Funny how it takes me all day to construct the conjecture and yet it's already proven or proved within minutes. ;) Thanks for the Euler Totient reference!